# custom post type tag lists and link to post

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm a newbie in custom post type. and so far I've been able to customize list of post (`archive.php` or `archive-xxx.php`), and link to individual post (`single.php` or `single-xxx.php`). All these works good.

However, when retrieving tag list or list of post of a specific tag, it uses archive.php and list all posts under the specific custom post type.

[question]
How can I fetch list of all tags for this post_type, with posts underneath each tag?

`tag1

   post 1

   post 2`

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @Brady my post was trimmed. Just added the question above. My archive.php has only simple WP_Query for all posts under post_type album, and a failing code trying to retrieve all tags under post_type album. When clicking on the tag link, such as  'http://domain.com/album-tags/test' returns the list of all posts for the post_type album, similar to 'http://domain.com/album/'

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
global $post;
$tmp_post = $post;

//First get the list of terms

$terms = get_terms("post_tag");

//then loop over the list and get the posts of each term
echo "<ul>";
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $args = array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'tag' =>  $term->slug, 'post_type' => 'album');
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    if (count($myposts) > 0){
        echo "<li>" .$term->name . "<ul>";
        foreach( $myposts as $post ){ 
            setup_postdata($post); 
            echo '<li><a href="'.the_permalink(); .'">'.the_title().'</a></li>';
        }
        echo "</ul></li>";
    }
}
echo "</ul>";
$post = $tmp_post;
```

Comment: placed your code in archive.php, but it returned blank, for both http://domain.com/album-tags/ as well as http://domain.com/album-tags/test. What possibly goes wrong?